# What does the following expression do?

Tags: odoo-13

What does the following expression do?

```
default=lambda self: ('New')
```

The exact expression is:

```
book_internal_code = fields.Char(
        string='Book Code', required=True, copy=False, readonly=True, index=True, default=lambda self: ('New'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is same as `default='New'`

But it creates a lambta that is executed when record is created.
For example `default=lambda self: self.env.user` sets default value as current user

Comment: Understood. Thank You